# Time Difference of One Item, Two Fields, Grouped by Days - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Controller**

```
@clock_events = ClockEvent.where(user_id: current_user.id)

@clock_event_days = @clock_events.group_by { |t| t.clock_in.beginning_of_day }

@clock_out = ClockEvent.where(user_id: current_user.id, clock_out: nil).last
```

**View**

```
<% if @clock_events.exists? %>
        <div class="row">
          <% @clock_event_days.each do |day, clock_events| %>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="list-group">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= day.strftime("%A, %B #{day.day.ordinalize}") %></h4>
                <% clock_events.each do |clock_event| %>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text time-group">
                    <%= clock_event.clock_in.strftime("%l:%M%p") %>
                      <% if clock_event.clock_out.present? %>
                        -
                        <%= clock_event.clock_out.strftime("%l:%M%p") %> -
                          <%= sprintf "%.2f", ((clock_event.clock_out - clock_event.clock_in) / 1.hour) %> hrs
                            <% end %>
                  </p>
                  <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class="daily-total">
                <strong>Total: **need total here**</strong><br>
              </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

**Result**

```
Friday, February 17th
5:15PM - 6:15PM - 1.00 hrs
5:29PM - 5:41PM - 0.21 hrs
5:49PM - 6:45PM - 0.94 hrs
6:49PM - 6:49PM - 0.00 hrs
6:50PM - 6:57PM - 0.11 hrs
Total:

Saturday, February 18th
4:45PM - 4:52PM - 0.11 hrs
Total:
```

Can some one help me get the total hours for each day and then for the entire week (Friday-Thursday)?

I am guessing I should be using the model for getting the time difference instead of using the view...but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a variable to track this in the view is the most straightforward solution, even if it's maybe not the most elegant one.

```
<% total_hours = 0 %>
<% clock_events.each do |clock_event| %>
  <% total_hours += (clock_event.clock_out - clock_event.clock_in) %>
<% end %>
```

and then output it

```
<strong>Total: <%= total_hours / 1.hour %></strong><br>
```

**Edit 1:**

You could also clean things up a bit by adding this in the model, something like

```rb
class ClockEvent < ApplicationRecord
  # ..
      
  def duration
    clock_out - clock_in
  end
end
```

and use that in the view

```
<% total_hours += clock_event.duration %>
    ...    
<%= sprintf "%.2f hrs", (clock_event.duration / 1.hour) %>
```

**Edit 2:**

You can clean it up even more by skipping the `total_hours` variable all together and do this.

```
<%= clock_events.sum(&:duration) / 1.hour %>
```

Comment: **Wow, the answer couldn't be more simple and perfect.** I was over complicating it by a million different ways. THANK YOU!!